# Ignite on YARN log level not obeyed

Tags: hadoop-yarn, ignite

In our ignite.sh it is specifically assigned a level of `INFO` but in the actual container logs it is printing `DEBUG` level logs.

In the `ignite.sh`:

```
JVM_OPTS= " ... -Djava.util.config.file=/data/ignite/apache-ignite-2.1.0/config/java.util.logging.properties"
```

In the `java.util.logging.properties`

```
handlers=org.apache.ignite.logger.java.JavaLoggerFileHandler
org.apache.ignite.logger.java.JavaLoggerFileHandler.level=INFO
```

This configuration prints out logs correctly when ran outside YARN but not when in YARN. How to fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can configure it by *IGNITE_JVM_OPTS* option. More details you can find [here](https://apacheignite.readme.io/docs/yarn-deployment#configuration). Just add the following line in your property file:

```
IGNITE_JVM_OPTS= ... -Djava.util.config.file=/data/ignite/apache-ignite-woo-2.1.0/config/java.util.logging.properties
```

Comment: In the doc you have given that property is listed as IGNITE_JVM_OPTS . Which one to use?

Comment: Sorry, IGNITE_JVM_OPTS is correct. I've updated my answer.

Comment: sorry but I have tried this way as well and it is still printing out DEBUG messages

Comment: I had to re do the zip and update in HDFS - now it works